# onclick change css

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, class

I am making a simple calendar app in PHP and I want to change the `<td>` block style depending on what the user does. But I want that when the "menuclick" class is on, the other classes stop working until I click another block. The previous block should be turned off as well. Thanks in advance.

```
echo'<td onclick=className="menuclick"; onmouseover=className="menuon"; onmouseout=className="menuoff";>' . $countDay++ . "</td>"
```

Comment: You'll need to clarify your question and your code. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, and your code doesn't look like valid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want using the following:

```
echo '<td onclick="this.className=\'menuclick\';" onmouseover="this.className=\'menuon\';" onmouseout="this.className=\'menuoff\';">'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WDu9v/

Seeing as though everyone is giving a jquery answer and jbabey is complaining about inline js:

```
$('td').each(function() {
    $(this).mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass('menuon');
    });
    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass('menuoff');
    });
    $(this).click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass('menuclick');
    }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WDu9v/1/

Comment: Inline event handlers are not good practice.

Comment: I'm only answering the question with what he's given - I would have gone the jquery route but as that is not tagged then you can't give that type of answer

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a look at http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

```
  $("#menuItemId").addClass(function(index, currentClass) {
    var addedClass;

    if ( currentClass === "menuon" ) {
      addedClass = "menuoff";

      alert("menu has class "+addedClass+" now");

    }

    return addedClass;
  });
```

If you want to remove a class or certain "state": http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to do it inline, it's a bit complicated.
I'd rather use jQuery and do something like this:

HTML:

```
<td class="menuClickable">Whatever...</td>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).load(function() {
    $('.menuClickable').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('menuon');
        $(this).addClass('menuClick');
    });
});
```

Of course, this is just the quick & dirty version...